# RVM Installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I am trying to install rvm on ubuntu 11.10.
I have installed it using following command through curl.

`curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto-dotfiles`

On terminal it specifies that rvm has been installed properly and I have checked .rvm directory has been created properly in my home directory and in .rvm directory version file is present but when I write rvm -v on terminal it gives following msg

`~$ rvm -v
The program 'rvm' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm`

Please help.

Comment: Probably your current shell is not sourced after installation. Try closing current terminal and start afresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the PATH to your .bashrc file?

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/src/rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/src/rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

After you added it, reload it:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

EDIT: this is not recommended way of RVM, rvm does shell file initialization, if you need force this process run `rvm get head --auto-dotfiles`