# ERROR: Error running 'GEM_PATH=" qhen running "sudo rvm install 1.9.3-p194"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, rvm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installed Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM but command line doesn’t show ruby -v](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056008/installed-ruby-1-9-3-with-rvm-but-command-line-doesnt-show-ruby-v)

I try to run this comand
-> sudo rvm install 1.9.3-p194

but this errors appears and the instalation was unsuccessful

```
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 9610k  100 9610k    0     0   181k      0  0:00:53  0:00:53 --:--:--  235k
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p194 to /usr/share/ruby-rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #extracted to /usr/share/ruby-rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #configuring 
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #compiling 
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #installing 
Removing old Rubygems files...
-e:1: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
Installing rubygems dedicated to ruby-1.9.3-p194...
Retrieving rubygems-latest-1.8
Extracting rubygems-latest-1.8 ...

ERROR: Error running 'gunzip < /usr/share/ruby-rvm/archives/rubygems-latest-1.8.tgz | tar xf - -C /usr/share/ruby-rvm/src', please read /usr/share/ruby-rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/rubygems.extract.log
Installing rubygems for /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby

ERROR: Error running 'GEM_PATH="/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194:/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global:/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194:/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global" GEM_HOME="/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194" "/usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby" "/usr/share/ruby-rvm/src/rubygems-latest-1.8/setup.rb"', please read /usr/share/ruby-rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/rubygems.install.log`

WARN: Installation of rubygems did not complete successfully.
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #importing default gemsets (/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gemsets/)
Install of ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #complete
```

Comment: first of all why do you use sudo command before rvm? this link will help you in that https://rvm.io/rubies/rubygems/ . I don't thing that you have to use sudo. <br />

Comment: I don't believe this is a duplicate of the linked question. But, I do believe both this and the linked are off-topic for SO (better served on superuser SE).

Answer (score 0):

first of all why do you use sudo command before rvm? this link will help you in that rvm.io/rubies/rubygems . I don't thing that you have to use sudo. 
Also you can look into this question [error while installing ruby 1.9.3 using rvm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642632/error-while-installing-ruby-1-9-3-using-rvm) 
Also 'rvm install ruby' will install you latest stable version of ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an very old version of RVM that is packaged with Ubuntu, make sure to follow instructions from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/497756 - `gunzip` is no more used in RVM so this problem should be fixed.

Comment: i have follow the instructions to install rvm, but when i try to run this -> `rvm requirements`
the terminal show this:
`The program 'rvm' is not currently installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm`

Comment: i fixed my problem with this answer -> [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192730/rvm-installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192730/rvm-installation)